# Qt mouse tracking not working at all when mouse hovers over QListWidget

Tags: c++, qt, mouse

I would like to get mouse position inside my `QListWidget`. The tracking is fine when mouse hovers over all other `QWidgets` - `QMainWindow`, `QPushButton`, `CentralWidget`, etc., except `QListWidget`.

**c++ file: test_1.cpp**

```
#include "test_1.h"
#include "ui_test_1.h"

test_1::test_1(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::test_1)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->setMouseTracking(true);
    ui->centralWidget->setMouseTracking(true);
    ui->listWidget->setMouseTracking(true);
    ui->pushButton->setMouseTracking(true);


    ui->listWidget->addItem("aaa");
    ui->listWidget->addItem("bbb");
    ui->listWidget->addItem("ccc");
    ui->listWidget->addItem("ddd");
    ui->listWidget->addItem("eee");
}

void test_1::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << event->pos();
}

test_1::~test_1()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**Header file: test_1.h**

```
#ifndef TEST_1_H
#define TEST_1_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QMouseEvent>

namespace Ui {
class test_1;
}

class test_1 : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit test_1(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~test_1();

private:
    Ui::test_1 *ui;
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent*);
};

#endif // TEST_1_H
```

**Main: main.cpp**

```
#include "test_1.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    test_1 w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Output:

```
QPoint(359,141)
QPoint(358,141)
QPoint(357,140)
QPoint(356,140)
QPoint(355,140)
QPoint(354,139)
QPoint(353,139)
QPoint(352,139)
QPoint(351,139)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void test_2::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
  QPoint p = event->pos();
  QRect widgetRect = ui->listWidget->rect();

  if(widgetRect.contains(p))
  {
    qDebug() << "Inside";
    ui->listWidget->grabMouse();
  }
  else
  {
    qDebug() << "Outside";
    ui->listWidget->releaseMouse();
  }
}
```

Comment: Good job :) Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

The right way of solving this is inheriting `QListWidget` and implementing `void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)`

But you have also another option, like [installing](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#installEventFilter) an event filter on your `QListWidget`.

Add this in your contructor:

```
ui->listWidget->viewport()->installEventFilter(this);
```

And implement the event filter:

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
    {
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "QEvent::MouseButtonPress";
    }
    if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseMove)
    {
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << " pos: " << this->mapFromGlobal(QCursor::pos());
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the solution did not work for me. I had to grab mouse to make this work inside QListWidget.

Comment: Could you post your solution as an answer?